# Calendar Date Picker Not Displaying Correctly

Tags: javascript, datepicker

This was working just fine until one day it wasn't. I have a booking calendar on a website that now shows the css text instead of the actual fa-calendar icon. I am going to guess something is outdated. I do not know how to fix this. The code I am thinking is the culprit is this one because a line of this code is what is showing up instead of the actual calendar icon.

[Screenshot of Datepicker Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNRUV.png)

```
jQuery(function () {

    // Datepicker
    
    jQuery("#w_txtArrivalDate").datepicker({
    
        dateFormat : 'M d, yy',
    
        minDate    : new Date(),
    
        buttonText : '<i class="fa fa-calendar-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>',
    
        changeMonth: true,
    
        changeYear : true,
    
        showOn     : "button",
    
    });
    
    
    
    jQuery("#w_txtDepartureDate").datepicker({
    
        dateFormat : 'M d, yy',
    
        minDate    : '+1d',
    
        maxDate    : '+180d',
    
        buttonText : '<i class="fa fa-calendar-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>',
    
        changeMonth: true,
    
        changeYear : true,
    
        showOn     : "button",
    
    });
    
    
    
    ResetDates();

});
```

Anyone have an idea why this all the sudden stopped working correctly? I really don't know where to look, other than what I posted. That is the only code with the calendar icon in it.

Thank you in advance.

I don't know enough about jquery to fix this datepicker.
I looked in the js file and removed the two lines with the font awesome fa-calendar code I pasted above, but nothing changed. The screenshot shows what it is doing.

Any ideas or suggestions would greatly be appreciated. I need help and I believe this is the best place to ask about my issue.

Comment: Can you send me the link to the page so I can have a look? It seems CSS styling is broken

Comment: Use this link. https://newharmonyinn.com/nov/2022/11/18/hello-world/ - this is a playground site when I have issues I try to fix. Thank you.

Comment: That would be super great if that's what the issue is, however, I installed the jQuery Migrate Helper plugin and it fixed it on the main site, so it has to be a .js issue I would think.

Comment: Is the issue gone? Old version of jQuery was conflicting then, I guess

Comment: No, it isn't fixed. That plugin is only a temporarily fix. You said an older version of jQuery is conflicting, can you elaborate on this Dream Bold? How do I fix this instead of relying on a plugin for the fix? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On line 131 when you inspect the page source, `<script type='text/javascript' src='https://newharmonyinn.com/nov/wp-content/plugins/enable-jquery-migrate-helper/js/jquery-ui/datepicker.min.js?ver=1.11.4-wp' id='jquery-ui-datepicker-js'></script>` It seems you are using the datepicker plugin from jquery migrate helper plugin. That's why you should enable the plugin to get datepicker to work correctly.

[image: jQuery Datepicker in page source]

You can refer to [this](https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/wordpress-datepicker-theme/) article for the implementation of Datepicker in WordPress. Hope it helps!

Or you will need to add your own jquery and jquery datepicker in your theme/plugin

Comment: Thank you Dream Bold...I should be able to implement the jQuery into the calendar as you described. Yes, I activated the js from the jQuery Migrate plugin. I want the calendar to be able to function without that plugin, therefore, I must get busy. Thank you for responding. I appreciate your kindness and help.